# Scala - printing arrays

Tags: scala

It seems like the support for printing arrays is somewhat lacking in Scala.  If you print one, you get the default garbage you'd get in Java:

```
scala> val array = Array.fill(2,2)(0)             
array: Array[Array[Int]] = Array(Array(0, 0), Array(0, 0))

scala> println(array)
[[I@d2f01d
```

Furthermore, you cannot use the Java toString/deepToString methods from the java.util.Arrays class: (or at least I cannot figure it out)

```
scala> println(java.util.Arrays.deepToString(array))
<console>:7: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Array[Array[Int]]
 required: Array[java.lang.Object]
       println(java.util.Arrays.deepToString(array))
```

The best solution I could find for printing a 2D array is to do the following:

```
scala> println(array.map(_.mkString(" ")).mkString("\n"))
0 0
0 0
```

Is there a more idiomatic way of doing this?

Answer (score 115, accepted):

In Scala 2.8, you can use the `deep` method defined on Array, that returns an IndexedSeq cointaining all of the (possibly nested) elements of this array, and call mkString on that:

```
scala> val array = Array.fill(2,2)(0)
array: Array[Array[Int]] = Array(Array(0, 0), Array(0, 0))

scala> println(array.deep.mkString("\n"))
Array(0, 0)
Array(0, 0)
```

The IndexedSeq returned does have a stringprefix 'Array' by default, so I'm not sure whether this gives precisely what you wanted.

Comment: Or use array.deep.foreach(println) if it could be a big array

Answer (score 39):

How about this:

```
scala> val array = Array.fill(2,2)(0)
array: Array[Array[Int]] = Array(Array(0, 0), Array(0, 0))

scala> import scala.runtime.ScalaRunTime._
import scala.runtime.ScalaRunTime._

scala> val str = stringOf(array)
str: String =
Array(Array(0, 0), Array(0, 0))
```

Comment: This is awesome! Exactly like the console. By the way, do you know how to print the type part, for example, "Array[Array[Int]] "

Answer (score 17):

Adding little more to Arjan's answer - you can use the mkString method to print and even specify the separator between elements.
For instance :

```
val a = Array(1, 7, 2, 9)
a.mkString(" and ")
// "1 and 7 and 2 and 9"
a.mkString("<", ",", ">") //mkString(start: String, sep: String, end: String)
// "<1,7,2,9>"
```

Answer (score 6):

Try simply this:

```
  // create an array
  val array1 = Array(1,2,3)
  // print an array elements seperated by comma
  println(array1.mkString(","))
  // print an array elements seperated by a line
  println(array1.mkString("\n"))

  // create a function
  def printArray[k](a:Array[k])= println(a.mkString(","))
  printArray(array1)
```

Answer (score 3):

I rather like this one:

```
Array(1, 7, 2, 9).foreach(println)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get neat formatting of Array[Array[Somethings]] with custom separators for the inner as well as the outer array follows:

```
    def arrayToString(a: Array[Array[Int]]) : String = {
       val str = for (l <- a) yield l.mkString("{", ",", "}")
       str.mkString("{",",\n","}")
    }

    val foo = Array.fill(2,2)(0)
    println(arrayToString(foo))
```

This results in:

```
    {{0,0},
    {0,0}}
```

Answer (score 1):

The "functional programming" way to do this (as far as I concern) is:

```
scala> array foreach{case a => a foreach {b => print(b.toString + " ")}; print('\n')}
0 0 
0 0
```

Or if you don't really care about the spacing:

```
scala> array foreach{a => a foreach println}
0
0
0
0
```

IMHO, functional programming can get a little messy, if it takes too long to make this, I'd say just go with the imperative way.

Comment: it looks a bit "imperative" with all that `foreach`es more than functional.

Answer (score 0):

```
Array(1, 7, 2, 9) foreach println
```

Minor modification of rupert160's answer. No need for dots or parenthesis.

Comment: How is this different from the answer rupert160 gave over 2 years ago?

Comment: @jwvh no dots or parenthesis needed

Comment: And yet such important and noteworthy information was not included in your answer.