# Apache Spark in Scala not printing rdd values

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark

I am new to Spark and Scala as well, so this might be a very basic question.

I created a text file with 4 lines of some words. The rest of the code is as below:

```
val data = sc.textFile("file:///home//test.txt").map(x=> x.split(" "))

println(data.collect)
println(data.take(2))
println(data.collect.foreach(println))
```

All the above "println" commands are producing output as: [Ljava.lang.String;@1ebec410

Any idea how do I display the actual contents of the rdd, I have even tried "saveAstextfile", it also save the same line as java...

I am using Intellij IDE for spark scala and yes, I have gone through other posts related to this, but no help. Thanking you in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Printing array in Scala](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17634427/printing-array-in-scala)

Comment: Have you considered accpeting my answer?

Answer (score 2):

The final return type of RDD is `RDD[Array[String]]` Previously you were printing the `Array[String]` that prints something like this `[Ljava.lang.String;@1ebec410)` Because the `toString()` method of Array is not overridden so it is just printing the `HASHCODE` of object

You can try casting `Array[String]` to `List[String]` by using implicit method `toList` now you will be able to see the content inside the list because `toString()` method of list in scala in overridden and shows the content

That Means if you try

> data.collect.foreach(arr => println(arr.toList))

this will show you the content or as @Raphael has suggested 
`data.collect().foreach(arr => println(arr.mkString(", ")))`
this will also work because `arr.mkString(", ")`will convert the array into String and Each element Seperated by `,`

Hope this clears you doubt 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`data` is of type `RDD[Array[String]]`, what you print is the `toString` of the `Array[String]` ( `[Ljava.lang.String;@1ebec410`), try this:

```
data.collect().foreach(arr => println(arr.mkString(", ")))
```

Comment: This works as I tried this too. But is there any explanation to this? I would love to understand the details behind this, can you please guide me to a link or something?

Comment: I changed map to flatMap, with rest of the code being the same. Now the output I am getting is for each line, every word is split into letters. I wanted to understand how map and flatMap work. this is getting frustrating for me.

Comment: `flatMap` returns an `RDD[String]` by giving each element of the Array being returned by the map function it's own RDD row. Essentially flattening the 2D structure.