# Why printing List[Array[String]] does not output values?

Tags: arrays, scala, println

I am trying to understand the output which i got from below code, It shows some alpha numeric values prefix with `@`. how can i change it to `("Hello,world"),("How,are,you")`

**Scala Code:**

```
val words = List("Hello_world","How_are_you" )
val ww= words.map(line=>line.split("_"))
println(ww)
```

**output**

```
List([Ljava.lang.String;@7d4991ad, [Ljava.lang.String;@28d93b30)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output here is as expected. It just printed out the list with fully qualified name for the corresponding string with @ hashcode. Standard in most of the JVM languages.

Comment: You can also append flatten at the end to get list of strings.
words.map(line=>line.split("_").toList).flatten

Answer (score 6):

Add `.toList`

```
val ww = words.map(line=>line.split("_").toList)
// List(List(Hello, world), List(How, are, you))
ww == List(List("Hello", "world"), List("How", "are", "you")) // true
```

Otherwise `ww` is a `List[Array[String]]` rather than `List[List[String]]` and `println` shows hashcodes of arrays.

Or maybe you're looking for

```
val ww1 = words.map(_.replace("_", ","))
// List(Hello,world, How,are,you)
ww1 == List("Hello,world", "How,are,you") // true
```

Comment: OP needs `.flatMap`.

Comment: @GeorgeLeung `words.flatMap(line=>line.split("_").toList)` produces `List(Hello, world, How, are, you)`. But Op wanted `("Hello,world"),("How,are,you")` whatever this means.

Comment: Oh you’re right, I misread. Probably because I didn’t see nested brackets in the question.

Answer (score 4):

To [prettify `Array` printing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17635886/5205022) consider [`ScalaRunTime.stringOf`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/a3791d4d61bd584f27e4dac8765f753a27bb95e0/src/library/scala/runtime/ScalaRunTime.scala#L166) like so

```
import scala.runtime.ScalaRunTime.stringOf
println(stringOf(ww))
```

which outputs

```
List(Array(Hello, world), Array(How, are, you))
```

As explained by @Dmytro, `Array`s are bit different from other Scala collections such as `List`, and one difference is they are printed as `hashCode` representations

```
public String toString() {
  return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
}
```

instead of *value* representations.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps [mkString](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-convert-array-to-string-mkstring) is what you are looking for?

```
scala> val ww2 = words.map(line=>line.split("_").mkString(","))
ww2: List[String] = List(Hello,world, How,are,you)

scala> println(ww2)
List(Hello,world, How,are,you)
```