# Why is there different behavior for `.split` function in REPL and scala compiler

Tags: scala

Consider the following in REPL

```
scala> val  a = "1 2 3"
a: String = 1 2 3

scala> a.split(" ")
res0: Array[String] = Array(1, 2, 3)
```

Consider the following in compiler

```
  val s = readLine()
  println(s.split(" ")) // outputs [Ljava.lang.String;@5ebec15
  println(s.toList)     // outputs List(1,  , 2,  , 3)
```

Why is there different output for the same function, namely

```
Array(1, 2, 3)
```

vs

```
[Ljava.lang.String;@5ebec15
```

I would assume both have the same output

Am I missing something

Comment: You're missing http://stackoverflow.com/q/3328085/1296806 or http://stackoverflow.com/q/17634427/1296806

Answer (score 3):

The repl output is not the same as the `println` output. The `println` outputs the `.toString`:

```
scala>  val  a = "1 2 3"
a: String = 1 2 3

scala> a.split(" ").toString
res0: String = [Ljava.lang.String;@5f84486a
```

In some cases the repl will print out the `.toString`, eg. when the object is a List or a case object. But when it comes to an Array, it will be smarter and actually print the array's contents.

Comment: Would you know how would I have the `println` result for array to be the same as REPL?

Comment: Not sure what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following in a worksheet and i see no difference.

```
val s = "1 2 3"                                 //> s  : String = 1 2 3
s.split(" ")                                    //> res0: Array[String] =     Array(1, 2, 3)
  println(s.toList)                               //> List(1,  , 2,  , 3)
```

The return from `s.split` is an array in both cases. It is when you pass the array to the `println` function that it outputs a string which is actually correct.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your follow up question, not exactly the same output as the REPL, but the following two ways will print the elements of the array. Also see discussions in [Printing array in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17634427/printing-array-in-scala)

```
scala> val  a = "1 2 3"
a: String = 1 2 3

scala> println(a.split(" ")) // outputs a.split(" ").toString
[Ljava.lang.String;@5fd62371

scala> println(runtime.ScalaRunTime.stringOf(a.split(" ")))
Array(1, 2, 3)

scala> println(a.split(" ").deep)
Array(1, 2, 3)
```