# How to print array values in Scala? I am getting different values

Tags: scala

Code:

```
object Permutations extends App 
{          
    val ar=Array(1,2,3).combinations(2).foreach(println(_))
}
```

Output:

```
[I@378fd1ac

[I@49097b5d
[I@6e2c634b
```

I am trying to execute this but I am getting some other values.

How to print array values in Scala? Can any one help to print?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Printing array in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17634427/printing-array-in-scala)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3328085/scala-printing-arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `mkString`

```
object Permutations extends App {
   Array(1,2,3).combinations(2).foreach(x => println(x.mkString(", ")))
}
```

#### Scala REPL

```
scala> Array(1,2,3).combinations(2).foreach(x => println(x.mkString(", ")))
1, 2
1, 3
2, 3
```

When array instance is directly used for inside `println`. The `toString` method of array gets called and results in output like `[I@49097b5d`. So, use `mkString` for converting array instance to string.

#### Scala REPL

```
scala> println(Array(1, 2))
[I@2aadeb31

scala> Array(1, 2).mkString
res12: String = 12

scala> Array(1, 2).mkString(" ")
res13: String = 1 2

scala>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't print array directly, If you will try to print it will print the reference of that array.

You are almost there, Just iterate over array of array and then on individual array and display the elements like below

```
Array(1,2,3).combinations(2).foreach(_.foreach(println))
```

Or Just convert each array to string and display like below

```
Array(1,2,3).combinations(2).foreach(x=>println(x.mkString(" ")))
```

I hope this will help you