# Reading float values from a csv file in Scala?

Tags: scala

I want to send (integer) values from a csv file to a (Chisel) class here.

I just can't read the values from a csv file -  I have already tried all code snippets scattered around the internet. (csv file is in the format below ->)

```
1321437196.0,
-2132416838.0,
1345437196.0
```

Code I am using:

```
val bufferedSource = io.Source.fromFile("sourceFile.csv")
val rows = Array.ofDim[Int](3)
var count = 0
  for (line <- bufferedSource.getLines) {

    rows(count) = line.split(",").map(_.trim).toString.toInt

    count += 1
  }
  bufferedSource.close
println(rows.mkString(" "))
```

Output:

```
[Ljava.lang.String;@51f9ef45
[Ljava.lang.String;@2f42c90a
[Ljava.lang.String;@6d9bd75d
```

I have understood the error message and tried all various snippets mentioned here([Printing array in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17634427/printing-array-in-scala?noredirect=1&lq=1) , [Scala - printing arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3328085/scala-printing-arrays)) , but I just can't see where I am going wrong here. Just to point out, I don't want a Double value here but want a converted **Signed Integer** , hence that is why toInt.

Thanks will appreciate help with this!

Comment: split yields an array, you want `split(comma)(0)`. You might consider something simple like `"314.0,".stripSuffix(".0,").toInt`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"1.0".toInt` won't work. Need to go from `String` to `Float` to `Int`.

```
val bufferedSource = io.Source.fromFile("sourceFile.csv")
val rows = bufferedSource.getLines
                         .map(_.split(",").head.trim.toFloat.toInt)
                         .toArray
bufferedSource.close
rows  //res1: Array[Int] = Array(1321437184, -2132416896, 1345437184)
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
line.split(",").map(_.trim).toString.toInt
```

to

```
line.split(",")(0).trim.toInt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
val bufferedSource = io.Source.fromFile("sourceFile.csv")
val rows = bufferedSource.getLines
                     .map(_.split(",").headOption.mkString.toInt)
bufferedSource.close
```